# How can I feed live audio to a keras model in real time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

I'm trying to create a voice-activated goal horn. I've created and trained a CNN model, but I have no idea how to use it to make predictions on live data.

I want to make live class predictions based on the last second of audio from the built-in microphone to categorize the most recent audio as "YES_GOAL", "YES_WIN", or "NO_GOAL".

The end goal of my project is for a goal horn to play on iTunes every time I scream "GOAL!"

When I try to run my code, I get

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2200 but received input with shape [32, 1]

Here's my code so far:

```
import pyaudio
import librosa
import numpy as np
import time
import subprocess
import os
import sys
#import kbHitMod
import tensorflow.keras as keras

MODEL_PATH = "/Users/schoolwork/Documents/Goal_Horn_Project_Stuff/Goal Horn Program/Goal_Model.model"

GOAL_TRACK = "1 New York Islanders Overtime Goal and Win Horn || NYCB Live: Home of the Nassau Veterans Memorial Coliseum"
WIN_TRACK = "2 New York Islanders Win Horn || NYCB Live: Home of the Nassau Veterans Memorial Coliseum"
OT_GOAL_TRACK = "3 New York Islanders Goal Horn || NYCB Live Home of the Nassau Veterans Memorial Coliseum"
QUIET_TRACK = "4 pure silence"

PAUSE_COMMAND = "osascript -e 'tell application \"iTunes\" to pause'"

class RingBuffer:
    """ class that implements a not-yet-full buffer """
    def __init__(self,size_max):
        self.max = size_max
        self.data = []

    class __Full:
        """ class that implements a full buffer """
        def append(self, x):
            """ Append an element overwriting the oldest one. """
            self.data[self.cur] = x
            self.cur = (self.cur+1) % self.max
        def get(self):
            """ return list of elements in correct order """
            return self.data[self.cur:]+self.data[:self.cur]

    def append(self,x):
        """append an element at the end of the buffer"""
        self.data.append(x)
        if len(self.data) == self.max:
            self.cur = 0
            # Permanently change self's class from non-full to full
            self.__class__ = self.__Full

    def get(self):
        """ Return a list of elements from the oldest to the newest. """
        return self.data

# ring buffer will keep the last 1 second worth of audio
ringBuffer = RingBuffer(1 * 22050)

overtime = False
print("\nOvertime mode: off\n")

def play(track_name):
    subprocess.getoutput("osascript -e 'tell application \"iTunes\" to play (first track of playlist \"Library\" whose name is \"4 pure silence\")'")

    subprocess.getoutput("osascript -e 'tell application \"iTunes\" to play (first track of playlist \"Library\" whose name is \"" + track_name + "\")'")

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
   
    state = subprocess.getoutput("osascript -e 'tell application \"iTunes\" to player state as string'")

    model = keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH, compile=True)

    audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    
    # we trained on audio with a sample rate of 22050 so we need to convert it
    audio_data = librosa.resample(audio_data, 44100, 22050)
    ringBuffer.append(audio_data)

    # machine learning model takes live audio as input and
    # decides if the last 1 second of audio contains a goal
    if model.predict_classes(ringBuffer.get()) == "YES_GOAL" and state == "paused":
        # GOAL!! 
        if overtime:
            play(GOAL_TRACK)
        else:
            play(OT_GOAL_TRACK)
              
        # decides if the last 1 second of audio contains a win
    elif model.predict_classes(ringBuffer.get()) == "YES_WIN" and state == "paused":
        play(WIN_TRACK)

    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(format = pyaudio.paFloat32,
                 channels = 1,
                 rate = 44100,
                 output = False,
                 input = True,
                 stream_callback=callback)

# start the stream
stream.start_stream()

i = 0 # This is just an alternative to breaking the loop with kbHitMod

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    
    """
    kb = kbHitMod.KBHit() # detects if a key has been pressed

    ot = kb.getch()
    if ot == "o":
        if overtime == False:
            overtime = True
            print("Overtime mode: ON\n")
        else:
            overtime = False
            print("Overtime mode: off\n")
    elif ot == "q":
        print("Quitting... Goodbye!\n")
        break
    """
    i += 1

    if i >= 100:
        break

            
stream.close()
pa.terminate()

play(QUIET_TRACK)
subprocess.getoutput(PAUSE_COMMAND)
print("Program terminated. \n")
```

And my model:

```
import json
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow.keras as keras

DATA_PATH = "/Users/schoolwork/Documents/Goal_Horn_Project_Stuff/Goal Horn Program/data.json"

MODEL_PATH = "/Users/schoolwork/Documents/Goal_Horn_Project_Stuff/Goal Horn Program/Goal_Model.model"

def load_data(data_path):
    """Loads training dataset from json file.

        :param data_path (str): Path to json file containing data
        :return X (ndarray): Inputs
        :return y (ndarray): Targets
    """

    with open(data_path, "r") as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)

        X = np.array(data["mfcc"])
        y = np.array(data["labels"])
        return X, y

def prepare_datasets(test_size, validation_size):

    # load data
    X, y = load_data(DATA_PATH)

    # create train/test split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size)

    # create train/validation split
    X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=validation_size)

    # 3d array -> (130, 50, 1)
    X_train = X_train[..., np.newaxis] # 4d array -> (num_samples, 130, 50, 1) (I don't know where these numbers are coming from. They might not be right)
    X_validation = X_validation[..., np.newaxis]
    X_test = X_test[..., np.newaxis]

    return X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test

def build_model(input_shape):

    # create model
    model = keras.Sequential()

    # 1st conv layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    # 2nd conv layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    # 3rd conv layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    # flatten the output and feed it into dense layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

    # output layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))

    return model

def predict(model, X, y):

    X = X[np.newaxis, ...]

    # prediction = [ [0.1, 0.2, ...] ]
    prediction = model.predict(X) # X -> (1, 130, 50, 1)

    # extract index with max_value
    predicted_index = np.argmax(prediction, axis=-1) # [4]
    print("Expected index: {}, Predicted index: {}".format(y, predicted_index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create train, validation and test sets
    X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test = prepare_datasets(0.25, 0.2)

    # build the CNN net
    input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3])
    model = build_model(input_shape)

    # compile the network
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                    metrics=["accuracy"])

    # train the CNN
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_validation, y_validation), batch_size=32, epochs=30)

    # evaluate the CNN on the test set
    test_error, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
    print("Accuracy on test set is: {}".format(test_accuracy))

    # make prediction on a sample
    X = X_test[2]
    y = y_test[2]

    print(X_test.shape)

    predict(model, X, y)

    model.save(MODEL_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be painfully simple.

Using the model path, all I had to do was feed my data into my model like an argument to a function:

```
MODEL_PATH = "/Users/schoolwork/Documents/Goal_Horn_Project_Stuff/Goal Horn Program/Goal_Model.model"

model = keras.load_model(MODEL_PATH, compile=True)

# Generate mfcc 

Prediction = model(mfcc)
```